# Version Control: When does a theme update, become a Major or Minor change?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have come across something, I have seen referred to as 'Version Control'.  I assume this is the process of assigning a version number to WordPress, Themes, Plugins etc.

Is there some kind of 'standardised' model to version control?  For example, would a major change be considered when certain folders/files are modified?  Maybe its the amount of changes?  Similarly, what would be considered a minor change?

If there is no 'standardised model', then would it be fair to say that Version Control is pretty Subjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on the author of the plugin or the theme. But here is how [semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) works:

Lets say a plugin is versioned 1.2.0

```
MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes, (1)
MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards-compatible manner (2)
PATCH version when you make backwards-compatible bug fixes. (0)
```

Again, it really depends on the author, for example this [particular author](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/import-users-from-csv-with-meta/) versions his/her plugin `1.10.7.1` or in case of [Jetpack](https://en-ca.wordpress.org/plugins/jetpack/#developers), all versions are normally like `5.4` and sometimes versions with patches .

If you are concerned about a particular version, you should always read the changelog.

Comment: Thank you for this insight. :-)